# Filter column of lists in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, filter

So I want to filter a column of lists which should only contain specific items.

This my original table:

| id | code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [Hes3086, Hes3440, Hes3220] |
| 2 | [Hes3440, Nee8900] |
| 3 | [Hes1337, Hes3440] |
| 4 | [Nee8900, Hes3440] |
| 5 | [Hes1337, Nee8900] |
| 6 | [Hes3220, Nee8900] |
| 7 | [Hes3220, Nee8900, Hes3440] |

I want the rows which only have specific items in the lists: Hes3440, Nee8900, Hes3220

Which should generate the following output:

| id | code |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | [Hes3440, Nee8900] |
| 4 | [Nee8900, Hes3440] |
| 6 | [Hes3220, Nee8900] |
| 7 | [Hes3220, Nee8900, Hes3440] |

I am able to filter the dataset by making sure that at least one of the desired items is in each row, but this is not what I want.

Would appreciate any help!

thanks,
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `issubset` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
L = ['Hes3440','Nee8900','Hes3220']

df = df[df.code.map(lambda x: set(x).issubset(L))]
print (df)
   id                         code
1   2           [Hes3440, Nee8900]
3   4           [Nee8900, Hes3440]
5   6           [Hes3220, Nee8900]
6   7  [Hes3220, Nee8900, Hes3440]
```

List comprehension alternative:

```
df = df[[set(x).issubset(L) for x in df.code]]
```